# Jquery drop down not working on local host

Tags: php, jquery, function

In my Site I have a drop down which shows the cities, 
which is not working on my localhost but works on the Server..

I am using WAMP

```
$("#moreCities, #hideCity,#dailyAlerts,#hideSubscribe").click(function (){
          var a =  $("#subscribeBox").css("display");
          if (a="block"){
              $("#subscribeBox").slideUp();
          };
```

Comment: Have you tried checking FireBug to see if all the files have been loaded?

Comment: Hi Paul is there ny other way other than firebug

Comment: IE and Chrome also have developer tools/inspectors. Or you could go out of the browser with Fiddler or another network sniffer.

Comment: Does Ie 9 has the tools... which one.. I want to avoid installin anything to inspect this isue... Also strangely enough I notice the site is aligned at center in server but in my local env its comes left aligned

Comment: Yes, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cbowen/archive/2011/05/25/internet-explorer-9-developer-tools-deep-dive-part-1-introduction.aspx for more info from the source. Section 5 in particular for your debugging.

Comment: I would seriously suggest getting some other browser besides IE for developing, although it still has a high market share I cannot see developing on a platform that thinks something along the lines of "Error on line 10,302 in file index.php" when index.php has 200 lines of code is the best debugging tool. Develop with a modern browser and then deal with the Microsoft garbage. IE is for stodgy corporate intranets and not the average user.

Answer (score 2):

It's your `if` statement.

```
if ( a == 'block' )
```

That will check to see if `a` is equal to `block`

You are assigning `a` to the value of `block`

Comment: the Issue is not coming at the serve end only here.. the code is in  a php file

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that your javascript file is getting loaded on localhost, and that it's the exact same file on localhost vs. production?